# how to convert a string date into datetime format in python?

Tags: python, datetime

How do I convert a a string of datetime into datetime format in python so that it can be compared with another date?

```
string_date = "2013-09-28 20:30:55.78200"
abc = datetime.datetime.now()

if abc  > string_date :
    print True
```

Answer (score 183, accepted):

The particular format for `strptime`:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
#>>> datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 28, 20, 30, 55, 782000)
```

Comment: What platforms is %f supported on?

Comment: @JonathanLeaders I suggest you ask a separate question about that.

Answer (score 30):

You should use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, fmt)
```

`fmt` will need to be the appropriate format for your string. You'll find the [reference on how to build your format here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: You mean to say `dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, "YYYY-MM-DD %H:%M%:%S")` ?

Comment: @user1162512 That format will not be correct, check my updated answer.

Comment: not working with `dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, "YYYY-MM-DD %H:%M%:%S")` . Says format is not valid

Comment: It's not valid @user1162512, as you were told. For a start your string has fractional seconds, which you haven't accounted for in your format. If you read the documentation it'll help.

Comment: Thanks. It worked with the answer provided by @Veedrac