# Reverse str to datetime.datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime

How do you go about the string '2014-03-16 18:28:11' back to datetime.datetime. I was wondering if there an easier way than the below

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 16, 18, 28, 11)
>>> str(datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 16, 18, 28, 11))
'2014-03-16 18:28:11'
>>> complete = str(datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 16, 18, 28, 11))
>>> date, time = complete.split(" ")
>>> [int(x) for x in date.split("-")]
[2014, 3, 16]
>>> [int(x) for x in time.split(":")]
[18, 28, 11]
```

Then use each variable as inputs to datetime.datetime

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert a string date into datetime format in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068269/how-to-convert-a-string-date-into-datetime-format-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

You want `datetime.strptime`.

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(complete, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to return the microseconds, or whatever that last parameter is