# python: convert date timestamp to epoch unix time and figure out number of days remaining?

Tags: python

I want to convert `2014-08-14 20:01:28.242` into a unix timestamp `245293529385` and subtract this by the current timestamp in order to figure out how many days have past and are ultimately remaining by subtracting this value from 14.

Scenario: user signs up and I want to count down the number of days remaining in their trial.

Comment: One thing: pretty sure `245293529385` is not the correct timestamp, since it refers to "Wed, 16 Jan 9743 11:29:45 GMT" ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[time.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to the rescue! Use the format string `%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S.%f`. For example:

```
   import time
   t = '2014-08-14 20:01:28.242'
   ts = time.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S.%f')
   timestamp = time.mktime(ts)
```

Now to convert it to a datetime (from: [How do you convert a Python time.struct_time object into a datetime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object) ):

```
   from datetime import datetime
   dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

Comment: you could also do all this with `datetime`, without having to first deal with `time` at all...

Comment: `%f` means `Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left. 000000, 000001, ..., 999999` right? [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: @B.Mr.W. The 4th note [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior): "%f is an extension to the set of format characters in the C standard [...] When used with the strptime() method, the %f directive accepts from one to six digits and zero pads on the right." So it accepts any number of characters.

Comment: @user299709 thats a different issue, why don't you accept this answer, and post your update as a new separate question?

Comment: both `mktime()` and `fromtimestamp()` may fail for some dates on some systems. And they are not necessary, [use `datetime.strptime()` directly instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26132778/4279)

Comment: great answer! however mind that datetime object cares about timezones :) ("naive","aware" objects, etc..)

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts:

#### [Convert input time string into datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19068269/4279)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime('2014-08-14 20:01:28.242', '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

#### [Convert datetime object to Unix time ("seconds since epoch")](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279)

The result depends on what time zone is used for the input time e.g., if the input is in UTC then the corresponding POSIX timestamp is:

```
timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
# -> 1408046488.242
```

If your input is in the local timezone then see [How do I convert local time to UTC in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79797/4279)