# Extracting date and time from a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, date, time

I have a very simple list like this :

```
['Monday,30 December,2013', 'Delivered_it', '19:23', '1']
```

Please guide me how to extract from this list the date , status and time

**NOTE** : I don't simply want to extract it like a string but as a **date.time** objects so that I could do some analysis on it .

Comment: Please share your code and error if any. Please help us to help you. Please check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068269/how-to-convert-a-string-date-into-datetime-format-in-python

Comment: See [datetime.datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

data = ['Monday,30 December,2013', 'Delivered_it', '19:23', '1']
data = '{} {}'.format(data[0], data[2])
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(data, '%A,%d %B,%Y %H:%M')
print timestamp # 2013-12-30 19:23:00
```