# Convert encoded date values to Datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have encoded values for Day(0,6), Month(1,12), Week(1,52) and the year is 2014 in a list. I need these encoded values to be transformed into a datetime object/string date in python.

For example,

```
Day Week Month
6   3    1
```

This must then been transformed to "2014-01-18"

Comment: Can't see why you need Month here, a date can be uniquely identified from Day and Week.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: Check out these links: [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime) [how to convert a string date into datetime format in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068269/how-to-convert-a-string-date-into-datetime-format-in-python)

Comment: @RezaTanzifi I need to opposite of the post