# Convert string to datetime

Tags: string, python-3.x, date, pandas, type-conversion

I have a simple question - and it seems to be one asked many times before (see e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068269/how-to-convert-a-string-date-into-datetime-format-in-python)). Nonetheless, I can't solve it.

I got a pandas dataframe I read from a csv file. It contains a column with the name `start-plan` with strings in the format `'05-04-2017'` (April 5th, 2017). As far as I understand, it is a European datetime in the form `%d-%m-%Y`. 
Here  is what I do:

```
df = pd.read_csv('activities.csv')
```

This is what dataframe head looks like:

```
print(df.head())

       start-plan start-actual    end-plan  end-actual  user  late
0  12-01-2017   16-01-2017  11-02-2017  10-02-2017     1     0
1  11-05-2017   15-05-2017  10-06-2017  18-06-2017     2     1
2  20-08-2017   20-08-2017  19-09-2017  05-10-2017     3     1
3  10-12-2017   10-12-2017  09-01-2018  08-01-2018     1     0
4  25-04-2017   25-04-2017  25-05-2017  26-05-2017     4     0
```

I try to convert the colums like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series('start-plan'), format='%d-%m-%y')
```

I get an error stating that `time data 'start-plan' does not match format '%d-%M-%Y' (match)`

What am I doing wrong? Moreover, I have several columns in the same format that I would like to convert. Is there a possibility to convert them all at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a `pd.Series` out of `'start-plan'`

Try:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['start-plan'], format='%d-%m-%y')
```

You can also use the option `dayfirst=True`.

You can get it in one go like this

```
cols = ['start-plan', 'start-actual', 'end-plan', 'end-actual']
df = df[cols].apply(
    pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True
).join(df.drop(cols, 1))

print(df)

  start-plan start-actual   end-plan end-actual  user  late
0 2017-01-12   2017-01-16 2017-02-11 2017-02-10     1     0
1 2017-05-11   2017-05-15 2017-06-10 2017-06-18     2     1
2 2017-08-20   2017-08-20 2017-09-19 2017-10-05     3     1
3 2017-12-10   2017-12-10 2018-01-09 2018-01-08     1     0
4 2017-04-25   2017-04-25 2017-05-25 2017-05-26     4     0
```

Comment: I tried `df['start-plan'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start-plan'])` as well. Both seem to work! Thank you!

Comment: @Rachel that is because `pd.to_datetime` was able to infer.  If it happened to be ambiguous, you're better off being specific.

Comment: @Rachel, even I thought that pandas would infer but try df.loc[1, 'start-plan'].day. It returns 5 as day instead of 11. So piRsquared answer is the way to go

Comment: payback time little fella