# How to get Time offset (diffrence) b/w time.strftime and datetime.datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp, timedelta

I am getting time input in unix (milliseconds) and want to get time difference b/w given value and current time for that I did following. 1st convert posix into human readable then tried to minus 2 values but `-` doesn't go well with str.

```
/1000 is for millisecond reduction

t = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1496814300000/1000))
k = datetime.datetime.now()

j = k -t
print j
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning your timestamp into a datetime object directly:

```
import datetime
t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1496814300000/1000)
k = datetime.datetime.now()

j = k - t
print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution here

[how to convert a string date into datetime format in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068269/how-to-convert-a-string-date-into-datetime-format-in-python)

strptime is the key to convert string into datetime