# How To Calculate days Between Two Dates In Django

Tags: python, django

I want to calculate days difference between two dates in Django. i am trying this code:

My Model :

```html
dateDeDebut = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
dateDeFin = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
```

My classViewSet :

```html
class MyClassViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyClassSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if (condition):
            diff = (self.request.data.get('dateDeFin') - self.request.data.get('dateDeDebut')).days #never executed
        print(diff)
```

And I get this error :

```html
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'
```

Comment: `self.request.data.get('dateDeFin')` is a string that you got from the user when the form was submitted. It's not a datetime object.

Comment: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-do-i-calculate-number-of-days-betwen-two-dates-using-python' may this can help

Comment: How i can convert it to a datetime object? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068355/148726 See here for example

Comment: Why don't you get the values from the serializer, which has already converted them? Or the model itself?

Comment: I did this to get the values from the serializer :  diff = serializer.data.get('dateDeFin') - serializer.data.get('dateDeDebut')   But I still have the save error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution works for me

```html
class MyClassViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyClassSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if (condition):
            start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.request.data.get('dateDeFin'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
            end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.request.data.get('dateDeDebut'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
            diff = abs((end_date-start_date).days)
        print(diff)
```