# Python datetimezone format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have date in the following format `"2020-03-22T03:15:05+00:00"` in Python. I need to convert this to `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s"`. I am trying to do this using `dateutil` but could not find anything.

Can anyone please help

```
d = "2020-03-22T03:15:05+00:00"

print(d)

t = dateutil.parser.parse(d)    

time = t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

---

I need some idea to extract date and time from above code

Comment: Please, provide your code

Comment: edited the decription

Comment: Check this one, it's very close to what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068355/2265497

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `datetime.strptime()` plus `datetime.strftime()` from the standard library:

```py
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> d = "2020-03-22T03:15:05+00:00"
>>> t = dt.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
>>> t
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 22, 3, 15, 5, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2020-03-22 03:15:05'
```

Comment: With Python 3.7, the ISO 8601 string parsing has a dedicated method: `fromisoformat`.

Comment: Yes @Jérôme, indeed it does.  However, in this case the user is assumed to be parsing a strict and known input format.  So using [`_parse_isoformat_date`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/96b1c59c71534db3f0f3799cd84e2006923a5098/Lib/datetime.py#L264) would instead potentially run through a whole slew of code branches.

Comment: Good point. It makes sense to specify the format manually in this case if performance matters.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.7 introduces [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat).

```
import datetime as dt

d = "2020-03-22T03:15:05+00:00"
dt.datetime.fromisoformat(d).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```